# VBA pivot with dynamic data

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am trying to have a pivot pull data from another tab within the same workbook but I get an error. Any thoughts?

```
Sub RefreshPivots()

Dim SrcData As String
Dim PivTbl As PivotTable
Dim lastrow As Long

Sheets("EXP 7004").Activate
lastrow = Sheets("EXP 7004").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

SrcData = Sheets("EXP 7004").Range("$A$26:$AT$" & lastrow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

Set PivTbl = Sheets("EXP Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Sheets("EXP Pivot").Activate

Sheets("EXP Pivot").PivotTables(PivTbl).ChangePivotCache Sheets("EXP Pivot"). _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData)

End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Where? Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve].

Comment: The error is in this part; "Sheets("EXP Pivot").PivotTables(PivTbl).ChangePivotCache Sheets("EXP Pivot"). _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData)." It is a Ru-time error  '438.' Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Add the error in the question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below (the explanations are inside the code comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub RefreshPivots()

Dim ShtPivot    As Worksheet
Dim PivTbl      As PivotTable
Dim PivCache    As PivotCache
Dim SrcRng      As Range
Dim SrcData     As String
Dim lastRow     As Long

With Sheets("EXP 7004")
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set SrcRng = .Range("A26:AT" & lastRow)
    SrcData = "EXP 7004!" & SrcRng.Address(True, True, xlA1)
End With

' set the Pivot Sheet
Set ShtPivot = Worksheets("EXP Pivot")

' set the Pivot Cache
Set PivCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcRng)

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PivTbl = ShtPivot.PivotTables("PivotTable1") ' check if "PivotTable1" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If PivTbl Is Nothing Then
    ' create a new Pivot Table in "EXP Pivot" sheet, start from Cell A1
    Set PivTbl = ShtPivot.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PivCache, TableDestination:=ShtPivot.Range("A1"), TableName:="PivotTable1")

Else
     ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range (data in "EXP 7004" sheet)
    PivTbl.ChangePivotCache PivCache
    PivTbl.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This came up with a run time error. The PivotTable name is not valid.

Comment: @BenjaminWann what line are you getting this error ?

Comment: Else
     ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range (data in "EXP 7004" sheet)
    PivTbl.ChangePivotCache PivCache
    PivTbl.RefreshTable
End If.                                I tried to remove and the macro did nothing.

Comment: are you sure you have valid data from Column A until Column AT ? 46 columns ? and the data starts from row 26 ? not 2?

Comment: @BenjaminWann did you cope my entire code here ? or only bits of it ?

Comment: I copied it all in and replaced what I had. I had data to col 46 and starting at row 26.

Comment: @BenjaminWann try edited code (made a small change to `Set PivCache` line)

Comment: Works great now. Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this...

```
Sub RefreshPivots()

Dim SrcData As Range
Dim PivTbl As PivotTable
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Sheets("EXP 7004").Range("a" & Sheets("EXP 7004").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set SrcData = Sheets("EXP 7004").Range("$A$26:$AT$" & lastrow)
Set PivTbl = Sheets("EXP Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

PivTbl.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData)

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked.

Comment: @sktneer come one, you're better than this, don't use `Activate`

Comment: hehehe.. Actually I worked on the problem area and didn't tweak rest of the code. :)

Comment: @Shai Rado What would be the alternative to Activate in this case?

Comment: Okay tweaked it as you suggested. @BenjaminWann .Activate is not needed here in order to update the pivot cache unless you really want to activate some specific sheet here. Though I have removed them altogether, you may use it if required.

Comment: @sktneer +1 from me :)

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that. :)